# User can access Windows based Apache sites but not linux Apache server over site-to-site VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, isakmp, meraki

I have a user (Win 7 Pro 64-bit) in a satellite office (10.1.0.0/24) that is trying to access web services in our main office (10.0.0.0/16) over a site-to-site VPN between a a Meraki MX60W and a Meraki MX80.

They are able to access sites that are hosted on Windows machines (running Apache 2.2.x and IIS) but they are not able to access sites that are hosted on Linux machines (Debian 7 and Apache 2.2.x). They get the initial password prompt but can't get to the site itself. They are able to ping by both hostname and IP address and the target machine is also able to ping them by IP. All machines (source and target) can ping both gateways  (local and remote).

If I telnet on port 80 to the hostname and excute "GET /" it returns the default apache page. Dial in VPN (L2TP/IPSEC) users are unaffected.

The browsers do not have any proxy settings configured and it affects all browsers. I have restarted the dnscache service, flushed DNS and have had them run with the dns cache service stopped. I've had them reboot and run as a different user as well as on the wired and wireless network in that office. They are the only user in that office for the next while so I can't get them to test with another users machine.

Are there any additional steps I've missed in relation to troubleshooting apart from running a packet capture on both ends?

Answer (score 0):

Path MTU discovery was on but the MX60W device did not set it's MTU appropriately. Call with Meraki support got the issue resolved after ruling out client side issues.